# Modular Arithmetic Divisibility

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Prove that for all integers $n$, exactly one of $n$, $2n − 1$ and $2n + 1$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: Have you tried a few test cases? Here's a hint: $2n-1=3n-(n+1)$, so $2n-1$ is divisible by $3$ if and only if $n+1$ is. Do something similar with $2n+1$, and report back with your own thoughts shown!

Comment: would 2n+1 = n+(n+1) ?

Comment: Can you prove that for all $n$, exactly one of $2n-1,2n,2n+1$ is divisible by 3?

Comment: Im not following sorry

Comment: Which part of "Can you prove that for all $n$, exactly one of $2n-1,2n,2n+1$ is divisible by 3?" are you not following?

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: By the division algorithm you can write $n$ as a multiple of $3$ with some remainder $r$. ie. 
there exists $d\in \mathbb Z$ such that $$n=d*3+r$$ where $r\in \{0,1,2\}$. Compare $r$ for $2n-1,n,2n+1$.